# Set default zoom level of PDF

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, jspdf

I want to set the default zoom level of image displayed in PDF using jsPDF. 
I am trying to set it to either 75% or 'Actual Size'.
But it is not getting set.

I also used `resizeImg()` but that is not setting the zoom level.

This is HTML:

```
<span class="col-sm-3 padding0">
    <button id="downloadModel" class="btn btn-md btn-default"
            style="height:100px;width: 210px" 
            ng-click="downloadWorkModel()">
          Download Work Model
    </button>
</span>
```

CODE:

```
$scope.downloadWorkModel= function(){
 var image = new Image();
            var width, height;
            image.onload = function() {
                width= this.width;
                height= this.height;
                width = width*4;
                document.body.appendChild(this);
                image = resizeImg(this, width, height);
                console.log("image width: " + width);
                console.log("image height: " +height);
                var pdf = new jsPDF("l", "mm", [image.width, image.height]);
                pdf.addImage(this, 'png', 0, 0);
                pdf.save('workModel.pdf');
};


 function resizeImg (image, origW, origH)
    {
      var resize = 100; // resize amount in percentage
      //var mouseX = event.x;
      //var mouseY = event.y;
      var newH   = origH * (resize / 100);
      var newW   = origW * (resize / 100);

      // Set the new width and height
      image.style.height = newH;
      image.style.width  = newW;

      var c = image.parentNode;

      // Work out the new center
      c.scrollLeft = ((resize / 100)) - (newW / 2) / 2;
      c.scrollTop  = ((resize / 100)) - (newH / 2) / 2;
      return image;
    }
```

Default Image view in PDF-
[image]

Comment: Despite what you state, nothing in your code sets the PDF zoom level.

Comment: ok so may be resizeImg  is not the right thing to set zoom level. Any other option that can point out to the right direction?

Comment: You are confusing HTML functionality with how a PDF works. Your Javascript will not execute "onload" and the rest inside a PDF. The PDF that gets generated is created by the resulting render of the HTML *after* it is loaded. The default Zoom level resides in a separate object; either jspdf supports this directly, or you have to check the PDF specifications and insert one "manually".

Comment: I am generating HTML on server side and then converting it to image and then storing this image to byte array column in database. May be I need to scale the image at server side to accomplish this. See if you know at my server side question for the same- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793845/set-zoom-level-of-image-created-from-string-html-content